# Merge Array to Object Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array here:

```
var array = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Nork'], ['lastName', 'James'], ['age', 22], ['position', 'writer']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'James'], ['lastName', 'Rodel'], ['age', 25], ['position', 'programmer']
    ]
];
```

I created a function that will transform my function into obj array like this:

```
[
    {firstName: 'Nork', lastName: 'James', age: 22, position: 'writer'},
    {firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Rodel', age: 25, role: 'programmer'}
]
```

So I created a function to do that. However I am not sure where to start to enable me to merge them.

```
function changeData(array) {
  var obj = { };

}

changeData(array);
```

Any help?

Comment: I am a little confused. How do you want to merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`[].map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control#Description) over [**`[].reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control#Description)

---

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
>
> ---
>
> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Nork'],
    ['lastName', 'James'],
    ['age', 22],
    ['position', 'writer']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'James'],
    ['lastName', 'Rodel'],
    ['age', 25],
    ['position', 'programmer']
  ]
];

function mergeObjectArray(array) {
  return array.map(function(el) {
    return el.reduce(function(a, b) {
      a[b[0]] = b[1];
      return a;
    }, {})
  });
}
console.log(mergeObjectArray(array));
```

Comment: @GaaraItachiUchiha — I have provided reference links in my post. I hope that will help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) to loop over the first array along with a [**Array.prototype.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example) in its callback to loop over the sub arrays and merge them in a unique object:

```
var merged = array.map(function(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    obj[item[0]] = item[1];
  });
  return obj;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var array = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Nork'],
    ['lastName', 'James'],
    ['age', 22],
    ['position', 'writer']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'James'],
    ['lastName', 'Rodel'],
    ['age', 25],
    ['position', 'programmer']
  ]
];

var merged = array.map(function(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    obj[item[0]] = item[1];
  });
  return obj;
});
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this one:

```
var array = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Nork'], ['lastName', 'James'], ['age', 22], ['position', 'writer']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'James'], ['lastName', 'Rodel'], ['age', 25], ['position', 'programmer']
    ]
];

function changeData(array)
{
    var i,j;
    var ret = [];
    var tmp = {};

    // rotate through every line and create a temporary object which we push to the return array
    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        tmp = {};
        for (j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) tmp[ array[i][j][0] ] = array[i][j][1];
        ret.push(tmp);
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log(changeData(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map into your array and assign dynamic properties like this `obj[prop] = value`

```js
var array = [
    [
        ['firstName', 'Nork'], ['lastName', 'James'], ['age', 22], ['position', 'writer']
    ],
    [
        ['firstName', 'James'], ['lastName', 'Rodel'], ['age', 25], ['position', 'programmer']
    ]
];

var convertedArray = array.map(function(line){
   var obj = {};
   line.forEach(function(prop){
     obj[prop[0]]=prop[1];
   });
   return obj;
});

console.log(convertedArray);
```

Comment: Don't use `map` for the inner loop.

Comment: @Cerbrus forEach is better ?

Comment: Yea. `map` is used to modify the array. `forEach` when you don't want to modify the source array, but just loop over it.

Comment: Ok, got it ty !

Answer (score -1):

You have not specified how you want to merge the users. this will take your array of user objects and reduce all the results into a single object with an array of all values supplied.

```js
var array = [
  {firstName: 'Nork', lastName: 'James', age: 22, position: 'writer'},
  {firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Rodel', age: 25, role: 'programmer'}
]

function changeData(array) {
  return array.reduce((users, user) => {
    Object.keys(user).forEach(key => {
      users[key+'s'] = Array.isArray(users[key+'s']) ? users[key+'s'].concat(user[key]) : [user[key]]
    })
    return users
  }, {})
}

console.log(
  changeData(array)
)
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP did not specify what they wanted, however, they did say that they have already created the code to do what all the other answers do, but said they wanted to merge the result. with the only example containing an object not an array. This answers that question and why I have preceeded my answer with an explination to that end. Thank you for the downvote anyway.

Comment: The question is very clear in regards to the desired output format. This answer returns something completely different.

Comment: "I created a function that will transform my function into obj array like this", "So I created a function to do that. However I am not sure where to start to enable me to merge them." 

Doesn't look very clear to me...

Comment: If you think it's not clear, why did you answer instead of close-voting as "unclear"?

Comment: Because this answers that question based on the language used and the code that has been provided.

Comment: Look at that second code block in the question. That's the desired output format. The first block is the input format. The OP posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754501/convert-an-object-literal-into-an-array) for the exact opposite. Sure, the wording could be better, but nowhere is he asking for an array of values per key.