# convert an object literal into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array object here:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'Chris',
  age: 25,
  hobby: 'programming'
};
```

I need a function that will convert an object literal into an array of arrays even without knowing the key or the value like this:

```
[['name', 'Chris'], ['age', 25], ['hobby', 'programming']]
```

So I created a function to do that. However I am not sure where to start to enable me to merge them.

```
function convert(obj) {
 var array = [];


}

convert(obj);
```

Any help?

Comment: [`Object.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) + [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Why are you [swapping between these formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753457/merge-array-to-object-array-javascript)?

Comment: any specific reason for this? Object is much easier to parse and get specific value than iterating and comparing nested arrays! :)

Answer (score 2):

using `Object.keys()` and `Array#map()`

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'Chris',
  age: 25,
  hobby: 'programming'
};

function convert(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]]);
}

console.log(convert(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
1. Iterate through the object
2. Push the key and value in to array and then puh that array into answer array

```js
   var obj = {
  name: 'Chris',
  age: 25,
  hobby: 'programming'
};


var ans = [];
for(var i in obj) {
 ans.push([i, obj[i]]);
}

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys to extract all property names:

```
var arr=[];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){ 
     arr.push([key, obj[key]]); 
})
```