# merge arrays and convert to JSON string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, merge, addition

I have two arrays consist of strings
`["25","36","32"]` and `["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"]`

I want to merge them all together and want to produce JSON string something like this:

`{"GradeA" : "25", "GradeB" : "36", "GradeC": "32"}`

How do I do this in js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Array to Object Array JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753457/merge-array-to-object-array-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

And for an extra 2 cents I give you the forEach loop version of it. This is taking into consideration that each array is going to be 1 for 1 and in the appropriate order.

```
var grade = ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
var number = ["25","36","32"];
var obj = {};

grade.forEach(function(x, i){
    obj[x] = number[i];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code will give your expected output:

```js
 var arr1 = [25,36,32] ;
 var arr2 =  ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
 var gradeObj = {};
 for(var i = 0;i<arr2.length;i++){
   gradeObj[arr2[i]] = arr1[i];
 }
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(gradeObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b):

```js
{
  const a = ["25","36","32"];
  const b = ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
  const merge = (keys, values) => keys.reduce(
    (obj, key, i) => (obj[key] = values[i], obj),
    {}
  );

  const json = JSON.stringify(
    merge(b, a)
  );
  console.log(json);
}
```

with native [Reflect API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect):

```js
{
  const a = ["25","36","32"];
  const b = ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
  const merge = (keys, values) => keys.reduce(
    (obj, key, i) => Reflect.set(obj, key, values[i]) && obj,
    {}
  );

  const json = JSON.stringify(
    merge(b, a)
  );
  console.log(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var keys =["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
var values= ["25","36","32"];
var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i< keys.length; i++){
    if(values.length>i+1){
         obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
     }else{
         obj[keys[i]] = null;
     }
} 
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add a property and it's value to the object on each iteration:

```js
const keys = ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
const values = ["25","36","32"];

const result = keys.reduce((obj, key, i) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: values[i] }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Using [Array#map,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a series of object with one property each, then combining them to a single object with Object#assign, and spread:

```js
const keys = ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];
const values = ["25","36","32"];

const result = Object.assign(...keys.map((key, i) => ({ [key]: values[i] })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try** **[ES6 Destructuring Assignment](http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching) :**

```js
var obj = {};

var arr1 = ["25","36","32"];
var arr2 = ["GradeA", "GradeB", "GradeC"];

function f([...val1], [...val2]) {
    for (var i in val1) {
        obj[val1[i]] = val2[i];
    }
}

f(arr2, arr1);

console.log(obj);
```